# Find UTF8 characters with RegEx

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text

I have many files (xml, css, js, html)

and would like to see everyone who has "UTF-8" characters, because some files are in `ANSI` and others in `UTF-8 without BOM`.

I tried several "RegEx" to the query, for example:

`[^\x00-\x7F]` or `\X` or `\p{L}`

- In Sublime-Text I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> with RegEx
- In Notepad++ I used "Find All in All Opened documents" with RegEx

But both returned the documents in "UTF-8" and "ANSI".

It is possible to find only documents that have UTF-8 characters or only like "iso-8859-1"?

Answer (score 1):

> It is possible to find only documents that have UTF-8 characters or only like "iso-8859-1"?

No, that is not possible in UTF-8 without BOM.
The only difference is how to interpret the characters and NOT the characters themselves.